# Prestashop: Modify mailalert module to have more visible product quantity

Tags: javascript, php, html, prestashop

i'd like to have more visibile product quantity in order confirmation mail.

I added

```
 <td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em; font-weight: bold; text-align:center;"><big><big>'.(int)$product['product_quantity'].'</big></big></td>
```

inside mailalerts.php

but I'd like to optimize it.

I'd like to change text color inside cell depending on its value.

If number is 1 should be yellow
If number >1 should be red
I found this code but I cannot use it inside my file, thanks

```
 $('#mytable tr td').each(function(){

 if($(this).text() > 1)$(this).css('background-color','red');
 });
```

thanks

Comment: Did my answer solved your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set this inline with a [ternary conditional](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) concatenation :

```
<td style="padding:0.6em 0.4em; text-align:center;' . ((int)$product['product_quantity'] == 1 ? "text-color: yellow;" : "text-color: red;") . '"><big><big>'.(int)$product['product_quantity'].'</big></big></td>
```

Hope it helps.